# How to delete the filtered rows using Xlwings?

Tags: xlwings

I am trying to delete filtered rows using xlwings.

Ex.
I have filters like below

```
import xlwings as xw
filename = r"C:\Users\User\Xwlings\Input VAT_2021.12_rev.xlsx"
sht = xw.Book(filename)
sht.sheets['Vendor_code'].api.Range('A1:F1900').AutoFilter(Field:=3, Criterial:='TATA')
```

After filters like that, I want to delete the filtered rows.

Answer (score 0):

Xlwings should delete the visible rows so after applying the filter, delete the range (from row 2 assuming headers) to the last row.
When the filter is removed those rows not matching the criteria should remain.

```
import xlwings as xw

filename = r"C:\Users\User\Xwlings\Input VAT_2021.12_rev.xlsx"
sht = xw.Book(filename)
sht.sheets['Vendor_code'].api.Range('A1:F1900').AutoFilter(Field:=3, Criterial:='TATA')

### Get the max row to delete to or use 1900.
last_row = sht.sheets['Vendor_code'].range(1,1).end('down').row

### Delete visible rows from 2 to the last row 
sht.sheets['Vendor_code'].range("2:" + str(last_row)).delete()

### Remove the filter and only the rows hidden by the filter should now be left
sht.sheets['Sheet2'].api.AutoFilterMode=False
```